# CSS Attribute Content Selector multiple declarations

Tags: css-selectors, css

I have this in my CSS:

```
div#headwrap ul li a[href*="dev"] {background: #034769};
div#headwrap ul li a[href*="music"] {background: #A61300};
div#headwrap ul li a[href*="opinion"] {background: #b2d81e};
div#headwrap ul li a[href*="work"] {background: #ffc340};
```

So, my expected behavior is that where a link (a) within a list item (li) inside a unordered list (ul) inside a div with id "headwrap" has an href that contains "dev", the link will have a background color of #034769. If the link has an href that contains "music" it will have a background color of #A61300, and so on.

However, what I am seeing is that the rule is only correctly applied to "dev". If I reorder the CSS declarations (putting music first, for instance), it only gets applied to "music".

I'm testing in Firefox and Chrome, both are doing the same thing. Only the first one is applied.

Anyone have any ideas why?

Comment: Wild Guess: Is it because the semicolon belongs inside of the curly braces? #headwrap ul li a[href*="dev"] {background: #034769;}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `;` on the end of those declarations, like this (I've formatted them inside, but simply removing them solves your issue):

```
div#headwrap ul li a[href*="dev"] {background: #034769; }
div#headwrap ul li a[href*="music"] {background: #A61300; }
div#headwrap ul li a[href*="opinion"] {background: #b2d81e; }
div#headwrap ul li a[href*="work"] {background: #ffc340; }
```

- [Here's with the semicolons, not working](http://jsfiddle.net/YJ6Q2/)
- [Here's without the semicolons, working](http://jsfiddle.net/YJ6Q2/1/)

You only use the semicolons after a property declaration, like this:

```
selector { property: value; property2: value2; }
```

Comment: The semi-colon terminates the particular _attribute_ and should be within the braces. ` { background: #ffc340; } ` It's not strictly required since you only have that one background attribute, but you should use it anyway to avoid the bug you'll get when you add another attribute and forget to terminate the first one with the semi-colon ` { background: #ffc340 color: #000 } ` (oops)

Comment: Thanks, this turned out to be a very silly mistake and a result of switching between php and css frequently today - thanks to you both for your replies and helping me correct my error!